# SQL Update Part of XML string in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table a:

```
+------+------+------+--------------------------------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | Col4                                 |
+------+------+------+--------------------------------------+
|    1 | A    | E    |<?xml version .....<v> "OOOO"</v></vs>|  
|    2 | B    | F    |<?xml version .....<v> "KKKK"</v></vs>|      
|    3 | C    | G    |<?xml version .....<v> "LLLL"</v></vs>|   
|    4 | B    | E    |<?xml version .....<v> "MMMM"</v></vs>|     
|    5 | T    | G    |<?xml version .....<v> "NNNN"</v></vs>| 
+------+------+------+--------------------------------------+
```

How would I update the xml between the ""?

Below is my attempt, which results in updating col4 to NewValue 1 - x. Basically it doesn't keep the xml format.

```
UPDATE sf
SET sf.col4 = 
 (CASE col4
        WHEN '%OOOO%'
        THEN '%NewValue1%'
        WHEN '%KKKK%'
        THEN '%NewValue2%'
        WHEN '%LLLL%'
        THEN '%NewValue3%'
        WHEN '%MMMM%'
        THEN '%NewValue4%'
        WHEN '%NNNN%'
        THEN '%NewValue5%'
        END)
```

Expected Result:

```
+------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | Col4                                      |
+------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
|    1 | A    | E    |<?xml version .....<v> "NewValue1"</v></vs>|  
|    2 | B    | F    |<?xml version .....<v> "NewValue2"</v></vs>|      
|    3 | C    | G    |<?xml version .....<v> "NewValue3"</v></vs>|   
|    4 | B    | E    |<?xml version .....<v> "NewValue4"</v></vs>|     
|    5 | T    | G    |<?xml version .....<v> "NewValue5"</v></vs>| 
+------+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

> Col4 is data type : nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: What is the datatype for 'col4' and what is the expected result?

Comment: @RajaYuvi I expect only the values between " " in the xml col4 to update. Such as <?xml......"NewValue1"...</vs> instead of <?xml......"OOOO"...</vs>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Replace`

Can u try this:-

```
UPDATE sf
SET    sf.col4 = ( CASE 
                     WHEN col4 like '%OOOO%' THEN Replace(Col4, 'OOOO', 'NewValue1')
                     WHEN col4 like '%KKKK%' THEN Replace(Col4, 'KKKK', 'NewValue2')
                     WHEN col4 like '%LLLL%' THEN Replace(Col4, 'LLLL', 'NewValue3')
                     WHEN col4 like '%MMMM%' THEN Replace(Col4, 'MMMM', 'NewValue4')
                     WHEN col4 like '%NNNN%' THEN Replace(Col4, 'NNNN', 'NewValue5')
                   END )
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @AlkippeNikephoros, If this is the solution for you - great! But keep in mind, that modifying XML data via string operations might bring up strange side effects. Just imagine an XML which has your search string on another place too, or an XML which contains "OOOO" *and* "LLLL". Don't know if this is possible in your case, but I would handle XML-data with XML methods...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a look on a solution using the XML abilities:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 INT,col2 VARCHAR(10),col3 VARCHAR(10),Col4 XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'A','E','<?xml version="1.0"?><vs><v> "OOOO"</v></vs>')  
,(2,'B','F','<?xml version="1.0"?><vs><v> "KKKK"</v></vs>')     
,(3,'C','G','<?xml version="1.0"?><vs><v> "LLLL"</v></vs>')  
,(4,'B','E','<?xml version="1.0"?><vs><v> "MMMM"</v></vs>')    
,(5,'T','G','<?xml version="1.0"?><vs><v> "NNNN"</v></vs>');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

/*
1   A   E   <vs><v> "OOOO"</v></vs>
2   B   F   <vs><v> "KKKK"</v></vs>
3   C   G   <vs><v> "LLLL"</v></vs>
4   B   E   <vs><v> "MMMM"</v></vs>
5   T   G   <vs><v> "NNNN"</v></vs>
*/
```

Now you query and update this:

```
WITH MyData AS
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,tbl.Col4.value('(/vs/v)[1]','varchar(max)') AS ContentV
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
,ExtendedWithNewValue AS
(
    SELECT  *
           ,CASE  WHEN ContentV LIKE '%OOOO%' THEN 'NewValue1'
                  WHEN ContentV LIKE '%KKKK%' THEN 'NewValue2'
                  WHEN ContentV LIKE '%LLLL%' THEN 'NewValue3'
                  WHEN ContentV LIKE '%MMMM%' THEN 'NewValue4'
                  WHEN ContentV LIKE '%NNNN%' THEN 'NewValue5'
                  ELSE ContentV
            END AS NewValue
    FROM MyData
)
UPDATE @tbl
SET col4.modify('replace value of (/vs/v/text())[1] with sql:column("nv.NewValue")')
FROM @tbl AS tbl INNER JOIN ExtendedWithNewValue AS nv ON tbl.col1=nv.col1;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

/*
col1    col2    col3    Col4
1   A   E   <vs><v>NewValue1</v></vs>
2   B   F   <vs><v>NewValue2</v></vs>
3   C   G   <vs><v>NewValue3</v></vs>
4   B   E   <vs><v>NewValue4</v></vs>
5   T   G   <vs><v>NewValue5</v></vs>
*/
```